# Cannot convert anonymous method to type 'System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority' because it is not a delegate type

Tags: c#, wpf, delegates

I want to compile this WPF code and get this error.

```
public void SetContentObject(Type contentType)
        {
            this.Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(delegate(Type input) //Error here <-
            {
                object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(input);
                this.Content = obj;//this.Content declared as object
            }, new object[]
            {
                contentType
            });
        }
```

**Edit 1:**

Using .NET 3.5. 4.0 not allowed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() method should pass the delegate without parameters (see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0b1bf3y3.aspx). You can pass your parameter be declaring it outside your anaimous method. UPDATED

```
public void SetContentObject(Type contentType)
    {
        Type input;
        Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(delegate
        {
               object obj = Activator.CreateInstance(input);
               this.Content = obj;               

        }), new object[]
        {
            contentType
        });
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, if forgot to put the delegate into Action instance

Answer (score 0):

You might be confused with Invoke and BeginInvoke:

```
public void Invoke(Action callback, DispatcherPriority priority)

//no priority is allowed below.
public DispatcherOperation BeginInvoke(Action a)
```